# How do I access list of structs with an integer argument (c++)?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have a series of structs:

```
const struct weapon Dagger = { 1, 40, 5, 20, 30, "Dagger" };
const struct weapon Sword = { 2, 35, 25, 40, 60, "Sword" };
const struct weapon Axe = { 4, 50, 10, 70, 80, "Axe" };
const struct ...
```

I want to arrange them so I can access each one by integer. I am trying to build a function that takes `int x` and `int y` as arguments, and returns the indexed struct's data. For example, if the function takes `2` and `3`, respectively, the value `35` from the `weapon` struct will be returned. Intuitively, I imagined the function body looking something like `return weapon[x].y`, although this does not work.

I do not know how to do this. The best alternative I can see is to use arrays instead of structs. Should I do this instead?

Comment: Since the values have different types, you can't have a single, completely uniform access pattern (at least not without some dynamic cost).

Comment: Can you show the definition of `struct weapon`?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this? This seems like an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: `const struct weapon {
  double kg;
  int damage;
  int defense;
  int cost;
  int frequency;
  string name;
  string description;
 };
`

Answer (score 1):

If you are only after the numeric data, then you could use two arrays: one for the data itself, and one for accessor function pointers:

```
struct weapon
{
    int val;
    int hp;
    int foo;
    // ...
    std::string name;
 };

const weapon w[] = {
  { 1, 40, 5, 20, 30, "Dagger" },
  { 2, 35, 25, 40, 60, "Sword" },
  { 4, 50, 10, 70, 80, "Axe" },
};

using accessor = int weapon::*;
const accessor acc[] = {
  &weapon::val,
  &weapon::hp,
  &weapon::foo,
  // ...
};
```

Now to look up property `j` in weapon `i` (both zero-indexed), you could say:

```
w[i].*acc[j]
```

Alternatively, you could perhaps represent your data as an array of pairs:

```
std::pair<const char*, std::array<int, 5>> w_alt[] = {
  { "Dagger", { 1, 40,  5, 20, 30 } },
  { "Sword",  { 2, 35, 25, 40, 60 } },
  { "Axe",    { 4, 50, 10, 70, 80 } },
};
```

Now the `i`th weapon's anme is `w_alt[i].first`, and its `j`th property is `w_alt[i].second[j]`.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question (selecting weapon based on index), using an array is a simple option, e.g.:

```
std::array<weapon, 3> const weapons =
{ { 1, 40, 5, 20, 30, "Dagger" }
, { 2, 35, 25, 40, 60, "Sword" }
, { 4, 50, 10, 70, 80, "Axe" }
};
```

Then, if you want, you can make specific references:

```
weapon const &Sword = weapons[1];
```

or make indices which you'll use to access the array:

```
enum weapon_id { Dagger, Sword, Axe };

// ...
do_something( weapons[Sword] );
```

Using `std::array` instead of a C-style array `weapon const weapons[] =` 
has a drawback that you can't deduce the dimension, but it has other benefits that make up for this.

---

For the second part, you may add a function that looks up the weapon properties by index. For example:

```
int weapon_lookup_number(weapon const &w, int index)
{
    switch(index)
    {
    case 0: return w.id;
    case 1: return w.power;
    // etc.
    }
}
```

with another function for looking up the string.

Using template specialization it'd be possible to have a function that looks up the member by index and evaluates to the correct type, however that would only work in the case of the index being known at compile-time.

Comment: That doesn't let you index into the struct fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a container that has indexed access, you probably want `std::vector`. Something like:

```
std::vector<weapon> WeaponVector;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your struct becomes:

```
struct weapon {
    int val;
    int hp;
    int foo;
    // ...
    std::string name;
};
```

You could use a `std::vector<weapon> Weapons` to store the `struct`s, sort it using:

```
std::sort(Weapons.begin(), Weapons.end(),
          [](const Weapons& w1,const Weapons& w2) -> bool { return w1.val > w2.val; }))
```

and access them using the vector indexes like: `weapons[some_num].hp;`, where `some_num` will correspond to the wanted `val`.

Comment: [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) reads much better than using the member `begin`. It also lends itself to making the code more flexible.